# Complex scipy optimization with shared values across constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to implement a structural optimization code using Python and the scipy.optimize library. The objective is to minimize the weight of the structure, and there are 5 inequality constraints for various material stresses and failure conditions. My plan is to use either the COBYLA or SLSQP methods.

I've done a few optimization codes using scipy in the past, but they were all fairly simple functions of the design variables (much like the tutorials in the official scipy docs). What I can't seem to wrap my head around with this problem is that all of the constraint functions are somewhat codependent.

I created a class that contains a bunch of extraneous data (material properties, loads, constant geometry parameters, helper functions...) that will get passed as an extra argument to the objective function and constraint functions. My question revolves around when to call the helper function that calculates several parameters that are used to evaluate the constraints.

- When scipy.optimize passes external arguments to the objective and constraint functions, is it a single instance of the object? Or does it make n copies for each function?
- Does the optimize module evaluate the constraints before evaluating the objective function?
- Does the optimize module evaluate the constraints in parallel or does it go sequentially through them from 0 to n?
- Can I call helperclass.updateSharedValues() once (for example, in either the first constraint function or in the objective function) and have the new values accessible to all other constraint functions? Or do I need to call it in every constraint function?

Here's some pseudo-code to help explain what I'm doing:

```
""" inside the main script that calls scipy.optimize """
cons =({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': G0},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': G1},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': G2},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': G3},
       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': G4})

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(weight, x0, args =(helperclass),bounds = bnds,constraints = cons)
```

A generalized example of the objective function

```
def weight(X,arg):
    helperclass = arg

    # calculate the current weight based on the design parameters and 
    # 10 other constants
    w = doStuff(X, helperclass.someStuff1, helperclass.someStuff2,...)
    return w
```

A generalized example of the constraint functions:

```
def G0(X,arg):
    helperclass = arg

    # call a function that calculates 10 other variables that 
    # are used by the 5 constraint functions
    helperclass.updateSharedValues(X)
    g0 = doStuff(X,helperclass.value1,helperclass.value5)
    return g0

def G1(X,arg):
    helperclass = arg

    # do I need to calculate these values in every constraint function
    # or can I just do it in the first one and all the others will have 
    # access to the updated values?
    helperclass.updateSharedValues(X)
    g0 = doStuff(X,helperclass.value2,helperclass.value3)
    return g1
```

Comment: Can all of your constraints ultimately be expressed as symbolic mathematical equations? Or does the `helperclass` have to do some dark magic which makes the functions e.g. discontinous? Could you give an example of the kinds of things you have to calculate there?

Comment: All of the constraints are inequality equations. At least one is dependent on a constant that changes based on two other parameters, and that function is discontinuous. If you're interested in seeing the full set of equations, pages 21 through 38 of the following document contains everything: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19940020254.pdf