# Optimization in scipy with shared computation in constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to do non-linear constrained optimization of an objective function in scipy.

My problem is that I have many constraints that share intermediate results. Something like:

```
def constraint1_i(x):
  T = f_i(x)
  return g(T)
def constraint2_j(x):
  T = f_j(x)
  return h(T)
```

where `i` and `j` run through 1 to n.

In other words, in each constraint, I run `f` on `x` to get an intermediate value needed to compute the constraint. The same thing gets run twice unnecessarily (when `i==j`, for all `i,j`)!

**Is there a way to somehow share computations across constraints to avoid the double calculation?**

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540731/complex-scipy-optimization-with-shared-values-across-constraints) is somewhat similar, but is more specific (and also has no answer).